# Rational number arithmetic

Tags: java, classes

I was assigned to make a Rational class to perform functions on fractions. After awhile I got it to work, but now I'm wondering how to simplify and clean up my code. Basically how to improve and use good Java practices so I can write better Java in the future.

```
public class Rational {

    private int numer, denom;

//constructors
        public Rational(){
            int num = 1;
            int den = 2;
            reduce();
        }
        public Rational(int num, int den){
        numer = num;
        denom = den;
        reduce();
        }
        public Rational(Rational x){
        numer = x.numer;
        denom = x.denom;
        reduce();
        }

//setters
        public void setNumer(int num){
        numer = num;
        reduce();
        }
        public void setDenom(int den){
        denom = den;
        reduce();
        }
        public void setRational(int num, int den){
        numer = num;
        denom = den;
        reduce();
        }

//getters
        public int getNumer(){
        return numer;
        }
        public int getDenom(){
        return denom;
        }

//Copy method
        public void copyFrom(Rational x){
        numer = x.numer;
        denom = x.denom;
        reduce();
        }

//Equals method        
        public boolean equals(Rational x){
        if (numer / denom == x.numer / x.denom){
        return(true);
                }
        else {
        return(false);
            }
        }

//Compare to method
        public int compareTo(Rational x){
        if (numer / denom == x.numer / x.denom){
        return (0);
        }
        else if (numer / denom < x.numer / x.denom){
        return (-1);
        }
        else{
        return (1);
            }    
        }

//Find greatest common divisor
        static int gcd(int x, int y){
        int r;
        while (y != 0) {
        r = x % y;
        x = y;
        y = r;
            }
        return x;
        }

//Rational Addition            
        public void plus(Rational x){
        int greatdenom = x.denom * denom;       
        int multx = greatdenom / x.denom;
        int mult = greatdenom / denom;
        denom = x.denom * denom;
        numer = (x.numer * multx) + (numer * mult);
        reduce();
        }

//Rational Subtraction
        public void minus(Rational x){
        int greatdenom = x.denom * denom;       
        int multx = greatdenom / x.denom;
        int mult = greatdenom / denom;
        denom = x.denom * denom;
        if (x.numer > numer){
        numer = (x.numer * multx) - (numer * mult);
            }
        else {
        numer = (numer * mult) - (x.numer * multx);
            }
        reduce();
        }

//Multiplication       
        public void times(Rational x){
        numer = numer * x.numer;
        denom = denom * x.denom;
        reduce();
        }

//Division        
        public void divBy(Rational x){
        numer = numer / x.numer;
        denom = denom / x.denom;
        reduce();
        }

//Fraction simplifier        
        private void reduce(){
        int divisor;
        divisor = Rational.gcd(numer, denom);
        numer = numer / divisor;
        denom = denom / divisor;
        }

    @Override
        public String toString(){
        if (denom == 1){
        return numer + "";
        }
        else{
        return numer + " / " + denom;
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Default constructor should be `0/1` or non-existent. All constructors should prohibit `0` as the denominator value. This ensures that `Rational` forms an [field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29).

Comment: I'm writing a similar rational number library for PHP.  I found that Wikipedia's articles on rational numbers and fractions are both very useful when it comes to how to implement the various mathematical operations.  You might want to look at those for ideas.

Answer (score 25):

Right, there's two parts to this review:

1. Is what you are doing 'good'?
2. Is there a better way?

The answer to the second question is 'yes', but we'll have to explore your current code to understand why....

### Current code, is it good?

Your code, for the most part, is neat, well-named, and generally understandable. Great. But, there are some significant problems too:

- your 'default' constructor creates the Rational `1/2` .... why? What's special about that....? Remove it.
- It is better to have one 'core' constructor, and then have the other constructors call it.... :

  ```
  public Rational(int num, int den){
      numer = num;
      denom = den;
      reduce();
  }

  public Rational(Rational x){
      this(x.numer, x.demon);
  }
  ```
- The [`equals(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) contract. If you override one of `equals()` or `hashCode()` you should always also override the other.
- your equals() method is oddly broken because it should take an `Object` as an argument. You have a situation where you may compare two rationals in a context where Java will call the `equals(Rational)` in one situation, but in a different situation (if Java does not know that the value really is a Rational) it may call equals(Object)... and that may return false. This will lead to some interesting confusion..... hmmm.
- you implement the method `compareTo(Rational)` but your class does not implement the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface. If you implement the Comparable interface you can do things like put your values in an array and then sort them using the native Java mechanisms, etc.
- your public interface methods should have comprehensive names, even if your variables do not: `setNumer(int)` and `setDemon(int)` should be `setNumerator(int)` and `setDenominator(int)` respectively. The same is true for the get* versions. Just because you were a bit lazy and used the auto-generated getter/setter mechanism in your IDE to create these methods, does not mean they are good names.
- you are not validating your denominator for division-by-zero.
- if your numerator is 0 you should have a special case for it.
- you should check for nulls for all input Rationals

OK, that's enough about the style.... let's go through the bugs... ;-)

- you do integer division a lot, and you are getting wrong answers (note that this equals() method is broken for other reasons too):

  ```
  public boolean equals(Rational x){
      if (numer / denom == x.numer / x.denom){
          return(true);
      } else {
          return(false);
      }
  }
  ```

  This is broken, because, consider two Rationals `1/1` and `99/50` ... when you do your math, you are doing integer division, so both of them have the result `1`, and `1 == 1` so your code will declare that 1 == 1.5, which is only off by nearly 100%....

  This same type of logic is used in the compareTo() method.

  Since you `reduce()` your Rational after every operation, your equals method could be as simple as `return numer == x.numer && denom == x.denom;`

OK, that's enough about the general issues....

### The better way.

Storing your Rational numbers is an important part of many programs. The underlying problem with your class is that it is Mutable. .... you can change the value of a Rational. This is unfortunate for a few reasons:

1. you cannot use it as a Key in a `java.util.Map<Rational,...>` because, if the value changes, it will break the internal hashing in the map.
2. similarly, you cannot store these rationals in a `java.util.Set<Rational>()`.
3. If you sort your data, the order will change if you change a Rational's value.
4. The instances are not thread safe.
5. serializing the instances is a problem.

This problem is well understood, and *all* the Java number-type classes are Immutable (Integer, Long, Double, BigInteger, BigDecimal, ......).

`BigDecimal` is a really good example of what you should be doing here. Have a look at [it's Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). Notice how all the mathematical methods do not modify the `BigDecimal`, but return a new `BigDecimal` with the right value.

Putting all of this together, your class should really look something like:

```
public final Rational implements Comparable<Rational> {

    private static final int getGCD(int a, int b) {
        .....
        return divisor;
    }

    private static final Rational checkRational(rat) {
        if (rational == null) {
            throw new NullPoiterException("Must supply a non-null Rational value");
        }
        return rat;
    }

    private final int numer, denom;

    public Rational(int numerator, denominator) {
        if (denominator == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Denominator cannot be 0");
        }
        // reduce the value at construct time....
        int div = numerator == 0 ? 1 : getGCD(numerator, denominator);
        // div is guaranteed to be a divisor, so integer division is safe
        this.numer = numerator/div;
        this.denom = numerator == 0 ? 1 : denominator/div;
    }

    public Rational(Rational other) {
        this(other.numer, other.denom);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // somewhat convenient hashcode ... it's a bitwise trick...
        // could be improved...
        return numer * 31 ^ denom * 31;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return other instanceof Rational
              && ((Rational)other).numer == numer
              && ((Rational)other).denom == denom;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Rational other) {
        checkRational(other);
        Rational difference = subtract(other);
        if (difference.numer > 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (difference.numer < 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    // return a new instance instead of updating ourselves...
    public Rational add(Rational addend) {
        checkRational(other);
        return new Rational(addend.numer * denom + numer * other.denom, denom * other.denom);
    }


    ....... Lots more .....

}
```

Comment: What would you think of the idea of including `reducedNumerator` and `reducedDenominator` as fields, with the specification that those fields may only be written once, the first time a rational number is used in a fashion that requires reduction?  When adding many fractions together, reducing each intermediate results will not only take time--it will in many cases increase the cost of the next addition.

Comment: For example, adding 1/30 to 20/720 will be easier than adding it to 1/36, since in the former case a single division will reveal that multiplying the first fraction by 24/24 will allow it to be added to the second, whereas the latter would require much more work.

Comment: @supercat that would, in a multi-threaded environment, make it very complicated.... requiring synchronization which will slow down everything, even single-thread.

Comment: If reduced numerator and reduced denominator can only be written once, I think the JVM would absolutely guarantee that any read would either yield a correct value or zero, would it not?  A thread which sees zeroes instead of legitimate values might end up doing redundant work, but I think correctness would be maintained.  Alternatively, if one wanted to allow for longer numeric types, one could have a field `reducedForm` of type `Rational`.  A rational number that was in reduced form could set that field to `this`, and otherwise any code which computed a reduced form could set it to that.

Comment: I'm pretty certain taht if the fields which hold the numerator and denominator are `final`, regardless of how complicated they might be, any thread which saw that a reference had been stored to `reducedForm` would be guaranteed to see an instance where those fields were correctly written.  Threading issues in that case would really be no different from `String#hashCode()`.

Comment: @supercat without sync, there's no guarantee that both redN and redD would both be visible to the second thread at the same time... one may arrive before the other. It is broken without sync.

Comment: If code assumes that it will need to reduce a fraction itself if `reducedDenominator` and `reducedNumerator` do not *both* read non-zero, what harm could occur beyond redundant work?  I'm pretty certain that `if (reducedNumerator==0 || reducedDenominator==0) handleReduction();` decides not to call `handleReduction`, there's no way a subsequent statement *on that thread* could still read zero from `reducedNumerator` or `reducedDenominator`.  Having `reducedForm` be a field of type `Rational` might be more flexible, but I don't see how `int` fields as described wouldn't be correct.

Comment: What you are describing is similar to what `String.hashCode()` does... but, the differences are: there's two variables in Rational; *every* method in Rational will need to use the reduced value (or would be more efficient and less-likely to overflow) with the reduced value). I'm not saying it won't work, but it won't be worth it.... I don't think. It will need benchmarking to prove....

Comment: How is adding 1/30 to 1/36 more efficient than adding 1/30 to e.g. 20/720?  The result of adding a/b to c/d, when d divides b [with quotient m], is (am+c)/d.  If am+c would risk overflow, one could divide m, c, and d by their greatest common divisor, but if not, why bother?

Comment: I think *why bother* has been my point all along. This is adding a lot of complexity for something that may or may not solve time (lots of duplicate checks in every method...). Care to perform a benchmark to prove it one way or the other? I would not spend the time on it myself.

Comment: "your 'default' constructor creates the Rational 1/2" No it doesn't! It declares local variables `num` and `den`, assigns the values 1 and 2 to them and discards them, leaving the class's fields `numer` and `denom` uninitialized.

Comment: @rolfl: In the `equals` method, it should be `==`, not `=` ?

Answer (score 15):

I am a mathematician who hasn't written a real line of code in a decade, and not a computer scientist, so please take what I say with huge grains of salt! Just thought you might think my perspective is interesting.

1. Why are you reducing so often? It seems computationally expensive. Of course you will want to reduce when the user asks e.g. what is my fraction, but in the meantime you may wish just to store and compute with un-reduced fractions.
2. It seems like your algorithm will handle negative fractions poorly, because when you run the Euclidean algorithm to reduce, it is random whether your numerator or denominator will wind up with the negative sign (unless I am confused). This won't cause mathematical errors, but it seems like sometimes you will tell the user his fraction is -3/5 and other times that it is 3/-5.
3. In fact, does your code know that (-3/-5) = (3/5) ? (Well, it does, because you have defined equality this way, but will it sometimes tell the user that their fraction is -3/-5 and other times tell the user it is 3/5 ?)
4. You define things by using the built-in division operation on integers. This seems a little circular mathematically (but may well be the right way to do things from a CS perspective) -- how do you define what 3 divided by 5 is if you don't already know what a rational number is? For instance, for your boolean equals, it seems more natural to use cross-multiplication and say

   ```
   return (numer * x.denom) == (denom * x.numer)
   ```

   as this is the standard definition of equality of rational numbers (and doesn't require things to be reduced, and appeals only to a statement working entirely in the class Int). Same complaint for when you compare fractions.

Comment: Hey Hunter, and welcome to CodeReview.... Your logic and reasoning, as expected is right.... The excessive reducing is a good point , but even better is your negative fraction observations... That's a flaw I missed in my assessment. Learned something. The integer division is broken in the source. In computers, `(-3/-5)` == 0 (his computer math is buggy). The circular logic is because this is an exercise for the asker... but you would be right for a non-trivial implementation.

Comment: The language (Java, in this case) does have a concept of rational numbers (single-precision floating point `float` and double-precision `double` are the primitive types), however a computer's storage of rational numbers is imprecise; consider how to write out 1/3: you get a repeating decimal 0.333... The computer has the same problem (with different rationals, since they are base-2 instead of base-10), and in addition can't correctly store particularly small (~10^-324 for `double`) or large (~10^307) numbers... nor numbers with digits near them. `1+10^-325 == 1` as far as Java is concerned.

Comment: The other issue is that the OP is using _integer_ division, rather than floating-point division. `3 / 4` is `0.75` mathematically, but Java will tell you it's `0`, since the integer will have all the decimal places simply chopped off. `3.0 / 4`, on the other hand (or `(double)3 / 4`), will correctly evaluate to `0.75`. That said, because of the imprecision of the floating-point format combined with base-2 data storage creating unexpected rounding errors, comparing the equality of rational numbers rarely works. Equality on the numerator and denominator is best.

Comment: (Also: `numeratorA * denominatorB` won't give precision problems, since they're integers rather than rationals, so your #4 is a fine answer. It's possible for them to _overflow_ or _underflow_, but that would require one of them to be outside the range [-2147483648, 2147483647].)

Comment: 10 votes! Congratulations for your [badge:nice-answer]! Welcome to CR, hope you stick around! :)

Answer (score 7):

You can make all the other constructors call the 2-variable constructor. For example:

```
public Rational(int num, int den){
 numer = num;
 denom = den;
 reduce();
}
public Rational(){this(1,2);}
public Rational(Rational r){this(r.numer,r.denom);}
```

Answer (score 7):

Your indentation style is a mess, fix that first.

Java normally uses a modified K&R style, like this:

```
function void style() {
    if (true) {
        // Code
    } else {
        // Code
    }
}
```

---

You should totally use JavaDoc!

---

```
private int numer, denom;
```

Do not declare variables on the same line for clarity purposes. It's easy to overlook the declaration of a variable if they are declared on the same line.

---

```
public boolean equals(Rational x){
```

You should only overwrite `equals()` with a typed variant. [Also, overriding `equals()` and doing it correctly is hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java).

---

```
public boolean equals(Rational x){
if (numer / denom == x.numer / x.denom){
return(true);
        }
else {
return(false);
    }
}
```

This can be shortened:

```
public boolean equals(Rational x) {
    return (numer / denom) == (x.numer / x.denom);
}
```

---

```
public int compareTo(Rational x){
```

You should [implement the Comparable interface if you create such a method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

---

All of your methods that accept a `Rational` do not handle the case if it is `null`.

---

```
@Override
    public String toString(){
    if (denom == 1){
    return numer + "";
    }
    else{
    return numer + " / " + denom;
    }
```

Never, ever for what ever reason is `int + ""` a valid way to cast an integer (or anything for that matter) to a String!

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    if (denom == 1) {
        return Integer.toString(numer);
    } else {
        return Integer.toString(numer) + " / " + Integer.ToString(denom);
    }
}
```

Or use `String.format()`.

Comment: Great comment! However, I do not agree with the function name : gcd is a perfectly fine function/method name for a module/class dealing with fraction. From a quick search : Java.math.BigInteger has it, the Python Fraction class has it, Perl 6 has it as a built-in... Also, having "get" in the name of a Math function is a bit awkward : cos() would be prefered over getCosinus() and so should gcd() over getGreatestCommonDivisior(). Again, I agree on everything else and find your comments relevant.

Comment: @Josay +1, style guidelines are fine but sometimes you need to make some compromises to make the code readable (especially since `cos`, `gcd`, etc... are fairly standard). If someone doesn't know what `gcd` is he sure as hell isn't going to know what `greatest common divisor` is. Stop the madness!

Answer (score 4):

Your are not handling overflow, and rational numbers can very easily get overflow, even when they don't get close to infinity. This code (assuming you have immutable rationals) approximates sqrt(2):

```
  Rational r = two;
  for (int i=0; i < 5; ++i) {
    r = r.plus(two.divide(r)).divide(two);
    System.out.println(r);
  }
```

Even just 5 iterations and your ints get out of range.  If your ints overflow, at the very least you should write (extremely complex) code to get an approximate answer, or (much better) use BigInteger for the numerator and denominator.

With BigInteger, after five iterations you get

```
 886731088897/627013566048
```